Should I fill these holes or start over?

I've extracted this complex mesh from a 3D model, but as you can see there are some holes that I am struggling to fill.
What can I do? But also, is it better try to fix this mesh or should I take this mesh as ref and create it from zero?

I guess it will be easier to redo it from scratch, you will have a better topology and less vertices

Probably, it's the best solution to avoid being stuck on this mesh for too long. At first, I thought that fixing it could help me learn something new and complex about meshes... but you're right :)
